# AWS EC2 instance good and fast to calculate MD5SUM of 1 TB file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, md5sum

Which AWS EC2 instance is good and fast to calculate MD5SUM of 1 TB file.

I want to run this operation in <5 mins, how can this be possible?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it take longer than 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

The Instance Type isn't as important as the speed of the disk.

[Amazon EBS volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html) can be configured for a particular level of IOPS and Throughput. If you need a faster disk-read speed, increase the parameters (but this can incur additional costs).

Also, some older Amazon EC2 Instance Types might need you to select "EBS-Optimized" to take full advantage of a high-speed disk. If you see this option for a given instance type, you will likely get faster performance by selecting it (this can incur additional cost). Newer Instance Types have this feature automatically provided.

**Bottom line:** You'll need to test various combinations to see what is satisfactory for you. Start with a modern Instance Type (eg `t3.large`) and a 'Default' speed disk. If that's not fast enough, increase the speed of the disk. Once it is working to your satisfaction, reduce size of the Instance Type to see if it continues to perform well at a lower specification (and lower cost).